# Haskell Type Coercion

Tags: haskell

I trying to wrap my head around Haskell type coercion.  Meaning, when does can one pass a value into a function without casting and how that works.  Here is a specific example, but I am looking for a more general explanation I can use going forward to try and understand what is going on:

```
Prelude> 3 * 20 / 4
15.0
Prelude> let c = 20
Prelude> :t c
c :: Integer
Prelude> 3 * c / 4

<interactive>:94:7:
    No instance for (Fractional Integer)
      arising from a use of `/'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Integer)
    In the expression: 3 * c / 4
    In an equation for `it': it = 3 * c / 4
```

The type of (/) is Fractional a => a -> a -> a.  So, I'm guessing that when I do "3 * 20" using literals, Haskell somehow assumes that the result of that expression is a Fractional.  However, when a variable is used, it's type is predefined to be Integer based on the assignment.

My first question is how to fix this.  Do I need to cast the expression or convert it somehow?
My second question is that this seems really weird to me that you can't do basic math without having to worry so much about int/float types.  I mean there's an obvious way to convert automatically between these, why am I forced to think about this and deal with it?  Am I doing something wrong to begin with?

I am basically looking for a way to easily write simple arithmetic expressions without having to worry about the neaty greaty details and keeping the code nice and clean.  In most top-level languages the compiler works for me -- not the other way around.

Comment: Quick note: Try doing this in a source file, not in GHCi directly. It will figure more things out for you that way, because it can look at the whole program, not deal with a line at a time.

Comment: This question is based on a whole program that is not working.  I've isolated this specific portion that the compiler is complaining about. I can post the entire thing, but I don't think it will help much.

Comment: Your question's been answered, but: "there's an obvious way to convert automatically between these."  Is there really?  What should `2^128 :: Integer` automatically become when I want a `Double`, or even an `Int64`?  And of course, going from non-integral types to integral types can't be automatic because of rounding.  In general, Haskell doesn't have subtyping or automatic type coercions; it has (constrained) parametric polymorphism.  But once a type has become concrete/monomorphic, values of that type are of *only* that type.

Comment: Can you try not to complain while asking questions?  It makes me at least less likely to invest effort in your question.  (Specifically, I'm referring to "in most top-level languages the compiler works for me -- not the other way around", and the similar sentiments)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you just want the solution, look at the end.

You nearly answered your own question already. Literals in Haskell are overloaded:

```
Prelude> :t 3
3 :: Num a => a
```

Since `(*)` also has a `Num` constraint

```
Prelude> :t (*)
(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

this extends to the product:

```
Prelude> :t 3 * 20
3 * 20 :: Num a => a
```

So, depending on context, this can be specialized to be of type `Int`, `Integer`, `Float`, `Double`, `Rational` and more, as needed. In particular, as `Fractional` is a subclass of `Num`, it can be used without problems in a division, but then the constraint will become
stronger and be for class `Fractional`:

```
Prelude> :t 3 * 20 / 4
3 * 20 / 4 :: Fractional a => a
```

The big difference is the identifier `c` is an `Integer`. The reason why a simple let-binding in GHCi prompt isn't assigned an overloaded type is the dreaded [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction). In short: if you define a value that doesn't have any explicit arguments,
then it cannot have overloaded type unless you provide an explicit type signature.
Numeric types are then defaulted to `Integer`.

Once `c` is an `Integer`, the result of the multiplication is `Integer`, too:

```
Prelude> :t 3 * c
3 * c :: Integer
```

And `Integer` is not in the `Fractional` class.

There are two solutions to this problem.

1. Make sure your identifiers have overloaded type, too. In this case, it would
     be as simple as saying

   ```
     Prelude> let c :: Num a => a; c = 20
     Prelude> :t c
     c :: Num a => a
   ```
2. Use `fromIntegral` to cast an integral value to an arbitrary numeric value:

   ```
     Prelude> :t fromIntegral
     fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
     Prelude> let c = 20
     Prelude> :t c
     c :: Integer
     Prelude> :t fromIntegral c
     fromIntegral c :: Num b => b
     Prelude> 3 * fromIntegral c / 4
     15.0
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Haskell will *never* automatically convert one type into another when you pass it to a function. Either it's compatible with the expected type already, in which case no coercion is necessary, or the program fails to compile.

If you write a whole program and compile it, things generally "just work" without you having to think *too* much about int/float types; so long as you're consistent (i.e. you don't try to treat something as an Int in one place and a Float in another) the constraints just flow through the program and figure out the types for you.

For example, if I put this in a source file and compile it:

```
main = do
    let c = 20
    let it = 3 * c / 4
    print it
```

Then everything's fine, and running the program prints `15.0`. You can see from the `.0` that GHC successfully figured out that `c` must be some kind of fractional number, and made everything work, without me having to give any explicit type signatures.

`c` can't be an integer because the `/` operator is for mathematical division, which isn't defined on integers. The operation of integer division is represented by the `div` function (usable in operator fashion as `` x `div` y ``). I think this might be what is tripping you up in your whole program? This is unfortunately just one of those things you have to learn by getting tripped up by it, if you're used to the situation in many other languages where `/` is sometimes mathematical division and sometimes integer division.

It's when you're playing around in the interpreter that things get messy, because there you tend to bind values with no context whatsoever. In interpreter GHCi has to execute `let c = 20` on its own, because you haven't entered `3 * c / 4` yet. It has no way of knowing whether you intend that `20` to be an `Int`, `Integer`, `Float`, `Double`, `Rational`, etc

Haskell will pick a default type for numeric values; otherwise if you never use any functions that only work on one particular type of number you'd *always* get an error about ambiguous type variables. This normally works fine, because these default rules are applied while reading the whole module and so take into account all the other constraints on the type (like whether you've ever used it with `/`). But here there are no other constraints it can see, so the type defaulting picks the first cab off the rank and makes `c` an `Integer`.

Then, when you ask GHCi to evaluate `3 * c / 4`, it's too late. `c` is an `Integer`, so must `3 * c` be, and `Integer`s don't support `/`.

So in the interpreter, yes, sometimes if you don't give an explicit type to a `let` binding GHC will pick an incorrect type, especially with numeric types. After that, you're stuck with whatever operations are supported by the concrete type GHCi picked, but when you get this kind of error you can always rebind the variable; e.g. `let c = 20.0`.

However I suspect in your real program the problem is simply that the operation you wanted was actually `div` rather than `/`.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell is a bit unusual in this way. Yes you can't divide to integers together but it's rarely a problem.

The reason is that if you look at the `Num` typeclass, there's a function `fromIntegral` this allows you to convert literals into the appropriate type. This with type inference alleviates 99% of the cases where it'd be a problem. Quick example:

```
newtype Foo = Foo Integer
    deriving (Show, Eq)
instance Num Foo where
   fromInteger  _  = Foo 0
   negate          = undefined
   abs             = undefined
   (+)             = undefined 
   (-)             = undefined 
   (*)             = undefined 
   signum          = undefined
```

Now if we load this into GHCi

```
*> 0 :: Foo
   Foo 0

*> 1 :: Foo
   Foo 0
```

So you see we are able to do some pretty cool things with how GHCi parses a raw integer. This has a lot of practical uses in DSL's that we won't talk about here.

Next question was how to get from a Double to an Integer or vice versa. There's a function for that.

In the case of going from an Integer to a Double, we'd use `fromInteger` as well. Why?

Well the type signature for it is

```
(Num a) => Integer -> a
```

and since we can use `(+)` with Doubles we know they're a `Num` instance. And from there it's easy.

```
*> 0 :: Double
    0.0
```

Last piece of the puzzle is `Double -> Integer`. Well a brief search on Hoogle shows

```
truncate
floor
round
-- etc ...
```

I'll leave that to you to search.

Answer (score 0):

Type coercion in Haskell isn't automatic (or rather, it doesn't actually exist). When you write the literal 20 it's inferred to be of type `Num a => a` (conceptually anyway. I don't think it works quite like that) and will, depending on the context in which it is used (i.e. what functions you pass it to) be instantiated with an appropitiate type (I believe if no further constraints are applied, this will default to `Integer` when you need a concrete type at some point). If you need a different kind of `Num`, you need to convert the numbers e.g. `(3* fromIntegral c / 4)` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

> The type of (/) is Fractional a => a -> a -> a.

To divide Integers, use `div` instead of `(/)`. Note that the type of `div` is

```
div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

> In most top-level languages the compiler works for me -- not the other way around.

I argue that the Haskell compiler works for you just as much, if not more so, than those of other languages you have used. Haskell is a *very* different language than the traditional imperative languages (such as C, C++, Java, etc.) you are probably used to. This means that the compiler works differently as well.

As others have stated, Haskell will *never* automatically coerce from one type to another. If you have an Integer which needs to be used as a Float, you need to do the conversion explicitly with `fromInteger`.