# Why can't I map a function that multiplies by a Fractional onto a list of Nums?

Tags: haskell, types, lambda

I want to make a list of numbers every `0.1` from `-150` to `150`.

To do this, I created a list, and then tried to map a Fractional multiplication lambda onto it, like so:

```
let indices = [-1500,-1499..1500]
let grid = map (\x -> 0.1 *x) indices
```

This makes ghci spit out an error.

On the other hand, both of these work fine:

```
let a = 0.1*2
```

and

```
let grid = map (\x -> 2 *x) indices
```

What's going on here? Why does multiplication of a Num by a Fractional only fail when applied to a list with map?

EDIT:
The error I get is:

```
No instance for (Fractional Integer)
  arising from the literal `0.1'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Integer)
In the first argument of `(*)', namely `0.1'
In the expression: 0.1 * x
In the first argument of `map', namely `(\ x -> 0.1 * x)'
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Ah, the monomorphism restriction, striking again.

Comment: @SamiN: I added the error I get to the question.

Comment: Yep, that's the monomorphism restriction. I'm too tired to give you a real answer, but search SO for that phrase. Questions about it have been answered probably hundreds of times.

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've discovered the "dreaded monomorphism restriction". Basically GHC will infer the type of `indices` to be a monotype like `[Integer]` instead of `Num a => a`. You can either provide an annotation like `indices :: [Float]`, or rework your definitions to avoid the restriction.

For example (not a suggestion), if you make `indices` a function: `let indices a = [-1500, -1499..1500]`, the inferred type is now `(Enum t, Num t) => a -> [t]`. The `a` parameter is unused but defeats the restriction. Then you can then do `map f (indices whatever)`. See much more information in the Haskell Wiki about the [**Monomorphism Restriction**](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction).

Comment: Could you specify where exactly one would put the annotation `indices:: [Float]` in this code? All of the haskell examples I've found online just use type inference.

Comment: Yes, you can write the type annotation separately from the declaration like `let indices :: [Float]; indices = [-1500,-1499..1500]` or you can annotate the right-hand side of the definition `let indices = [-1500,-1499..1500] :: [Float]`.

Answer (score 8):

This is defaulting.

Your `indices` variable, rather than being polymorphic over the `Num` typeclass as you might expect, is defaulting to Integer, at which point you can't multiply it by `0.1`, since `0.1` will resolve to some Fractional type.

You could force indices to be polymorphic with an explicit type signature:

```
let indices :: (Enum a, Num a) => [a]; indices = [-1500,-1499..1500]
```

although in practice you don't often want explicitly polymorphic lists in that way.

There is a page about the monomorphism restriction on the haskell wiki although it's not particularly succinct : http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction

Comment: Don't forget you'll also need `Enum a` in the signature.

Comment: Note that if you put these definitions in a file together then even without type signatures everything's fine. The monomorphism restriction still applies, but with the entire context available GHC can pick a *correct* monomorphic type rather than `[Integer]`. The way the defaulting works is not that dumb, it's just that entering bindings into ghci one at a time forces GHC to "work blind".

Comment: @Ben : I think that's not quite precise. You can't type `let indices` and `let grid` at the top level of a file. They're let bindings in the monadic style. And two separate `lets` in monadic style are not mutually recursive. If it was *either* plain `indices = ` and `grid = ` at the top level, or if it was a single `let` with two clauses as in `let indices = ... ; grid = .... ` then absolutely, you make an excellent point - defaulting is applied across entire groups of definitions.

Comment: @drquicksilver You don't need them to be mutually recursive, you just need them in the same compilation unit. The monomorphism restriction applies *after* type inference has figured out the most general type of every expression, so after it's already figured out that `indices` and `grid` have be `Fractional a => [a]` for the same `a`; it then won't default one to a type that's invalid for the other. Wrapping the OP's code in `main = do ... print grid` works fine. The problem in GHCi is purely that it has to compile the `let indices` binding before you've even typed `let grid`.

Comment: @Ben ah yes. As you say, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
let grid = map (\x -> 0.1 * (fromInteger x)) indices
```

-- grid [-150.0,-149.9,-149.8,-149.70000000000002,-149.6,-149.5 ...]

Answer (score -1):

the Following code worked for me

```
let indices = [-1500,-1499..1500]

let grid = map ( \x -> x /10 ) indices
```

it doesn't like the 0.1

For full explanation see section "Monomorphic trouble" on this [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Type_basics_II)

Comment: i am using The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.0.3 and the file just contained those lines and it worked

Comment: @Dan This code 'map ( \x -> x /10 ) [-1500,-1499..1500]' works on http://tryhaskell.org/

Comment: My original code also works on tryhaskell.org. It doesn't work for my version of ghc (Version 7.4.1).

Comment: @Dan I thought your code was not working because of the numeric thing issue.. I checked on hugs interpreter. It did not accept the code above as is but when I added 'indices :: [Double]' before indices, the code ran fine

Comment: @Dan I am stumped. maybe update the  question so some one else can shed some light on this.

Comment: @Dan It works in a full compiled file, because GHC can see your whole program at once, realise that you're multiplying some `Num a => a` by some `Fractional b => b`, and apply the monomorphism restriction to default all those polymorphic types to some instance of Fractional. When you do it in ghci, GHC has to evaluate each command one at a time. So `let indices = [-1500,-1499..1500]` is evaluated with no other context and `indices` winds up defaulting to `[Integer]`. Then the multiplication by `0.1` comes along, but it's too late to change the type assigned to `indices`.

Comment: @Dan I gave a more detailed explanation of basically the same phenomenon in my answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667662/haskell-type-coercion/14667979#14667979